# 5v 3v3 SPI Chip Select

Tags: spi

So we have a Kinetis MCU (Mk66fn2m0) which is 3v3, and needing to select a CS line of a 5V chip (CJ125 made by Bosch).

We used buffers for the main comms, but forgot the CS, just linking directly as a net and pcb trace.

Is there an easy way such as a pull-up resistor (and if so what value) to make the 5v slave's CS work with the Kinetisis 3v3 output pin?

Thanks

Comment: Is 3.3 V as logic 1 not enough?

Comment: Please provide links to the datasheets of the MCU and the SPI chip.

Comment: The min voltage for a logic high on the other chip is 0.7 * Vdd which would be 3.5V in our case

Comment: So we need to hit approx 3.5v for logic 1 for the slave device (CJ125) The processor is a Kinetis Mk66fn2m0, and as the PCbs are made, its a case of the simplest "mod" to achieve it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

One option as hinted but not fully explained in annie's answer is to play about with the tolerances of your voltage rails. If you increase the "3.3V" rail to say 3.6V and reduce the "5V" rail to 4.75V you may be able to buy enough margin to make things work while still having suitable power supplies for your devices.

If you attatch a pull-up but still hard-drive the output then the pull-up is likely to have little effect.

If the line on the MCU is 5V tolerant then you may be able to add a pull-up and drive the output open-collector either by using an explicit open-collector mode on the pin or by setting the pin to input mode to produce a logic high output.

Values for the pull-up will depend on how much capacitance the line has and how quickly you need it to transition from high to low. Some experimentation may be required.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to invert the CS signal? In that case you could use one MOSFET + 1 Resistor, although you'll need to cut through the wire at some place.

Yet, to be honest, I'd give it a try with 3.3V and perform some reliability tests.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm looking at the right datasheets, 3.6V is the max VDD of the MCU, and 4.75V is the min VDD of the Bosch chip, with min VIH being 3.325V. So you have plenty of margin without adding any additional circuitry.

Comment: But, his MCU is 3.3 V. I don't think it's a good idea to run things near their spec'd limit.

Comment: Nonsense. The spec'd limit for VDD has a ton of margin before you start damaging the part. Check the abs max rating if you don't believe me. Now, I'm not saying that there isn't some other reason s/he might not want to run at those voltages. But that was not mentioned in the question.